# TableView - Find out the number of cells selected in a single row

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have a table view with 5 columns and 4 rows. If I select say two cells from one of the rows, how can I find out this value (i.e. number of cells selected in a row).

I can find out the focused cell using

```
table.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell()
```

The number of selected rows

```
table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().size()
```

where

```
table = new TableView(...)
```

Comment: `table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().size()` does not give you the selected item; it gives you the number of selected rows.

Comment: `table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().size()` gives the number of rows selected and not the number of cells selected in the row.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said... You said in the question it gave you the selected item.

Comment: O sorry. I'll update the question

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells()` to get a list of all the selected `TablePosition`s. For each `TablePosition`, `getRow()` tells you which row it is in, so you can just count them up by row.

For example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TablePosition;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewCountSelectedCellsByRow extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();
        table.getColumns().addAll(Arrays.asList(
                createCol("Name", Item::nameProperty),
                createCol("Value", Item::valueProperty)
        ));

        final int numItems = 100 ;
        final Random rng = new Random();
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, numItems)
            .mapToObj(i -> new Item("Item "+i, rng.nextInt(20)))
            .forEach(table.getItems()::add);

        table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

        table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends TablePosition> c) -> {

            // table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells() returns a list of all selected TablePositions
            // Just iterate through it and count up cells by row

            Map<Integer, Integer> selectedCellCountByRow = new HashMap<>();

            table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().forEach( p -> 
                selectedCellCountByRow.merge(p.getRow(), 1, Integer::sum));

            // Display all row counts:
            selectedCellCountByRow.keySet().stream().sorted(Integer::compare).forEach( r -> 
                    System.out.println("Row " + r + " has "+selectedCellCountByRow.get(r)+" cells selected"));

            System.out.println();
        });

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();


    }

    public static <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> createCol(String title, Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> property) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        return col ;
    }

    public static class Item {
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final IntegerProperty value = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

        public Item(String name, int value) {
            setName(name);
            setValue(value);
        }

        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public final String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setName(final String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }

        public final IntegerProperty valueProperty() {
            return this.value;
        }

        public final int getValue() {
            return this.valueProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setValue(final int value) {
            this.valueProperty().set(value);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getName();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```